# Issue in installing Windows Driver Kit 8.1 Update 1

Tags: windows, driver, wdk

I am facing problem in installing "Windows Driver Kit 8.1 Update 1" from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=42273).I have already installed visual studio 2013 professional 2013.

error message is

> Setup can not locate 82c1721cd310c73968861674ffc209c9.cab